# Implementing searchable symmetric encryption over AES encrypted text file

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am using Java to experiment with implementing searchable symmetric key encryption. I am using the Java `crypto` libraries to encrypt a text file using AES. However, I want to be able to search over the encrypted version. Are there libraries that offer some implementation of searchable symmetric encryption algorithms? If not, is there a standard, basic algorithm used to implement searchable encryption for smaller programs?

Comment: You want to search for plaintext in ciphertext?

Comment: There are many different approaches (with different advantages and disadvantages), this is quite a modern research-topic and you will find a lot of papers through google-scholar (*searchable symmetric encryption*). It might be a bit more work than you think. [Here](http://outsourcedbits.org/2014/08/21/how-to-search-on-encrypted-data-searchable-symmetric-encryption-part-5/) is a nice blog of some researcher working on this (5 parts; i'm not sure if parts 1-4 are down). For a simple prototype i would recommend the ORAM-approach using [PyORAM](https://github.com/ghackebeil/PyORAM)